# Thymeleaf: Html tag inside a th:text

Tags: thymeleaf

Is it possible to have Html tag inside a th:text ?

for instance:

```
<h2 th:text="'LOCATION INFO Device &lt;strong&gt;' + ${deviceKey} + ' &lt;/strong&gt;  at ' + ${deviceEventTime} ">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, what you have works if you use `th:utext` instead of `th:text`.

```
<h2 th:utext="'LOCATION INFO Device &lt;strong&gt;' + ${deviceKey} + ' &lt;/strong&gt;  at ' + ${deviceEventTime}" />
```

I would personally format it like this, however:

```
<h2>
  LOCATION INFO Device 
  <strong th:text="${deviceKey}" />
  at
  <span th:text="${deviceEventTime}">
</h2>
```

(Which may or may not be possible, depending on your actual requirements.)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with this syntax `[(${brand})]`:

```
<h3 th:object="${brand}" class="text-center text-black mt-5">
All Products By Brand 
<span>
    <b class="text-danger">[(${brand})]</b>
</span>
```

The object in this case is a String, but you can use `${object.something}`.